# Should [observation] and [observational-astronomy] be merged?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, merge-request

[observation](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/observation) and [observational-astronomy](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/observational-astronomy) seem to more or less mean the same thing. Should these tags be merged? Which name should be favored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only difference seems to be that observation discusses a singular object, and observational-astronomy discusses multiple.

Looks to me that these tags could be merged since basically observational-astronomy encompasses observation and questions could be altered to define if the question is about a singular object or multiple.

Comment: Tag merge complete.